# App which will user to upload an excel sheet and update the sharepoint list with the rows in the excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, powerapp, power-automate

trying to build a powerapp which would help user to upload an excel sheet via app and update a sharepoint list with the rows in the excel sheet. Request to help/suggest how can this be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

We suggest you follow this video to upload excel files to SharePoint in PowerApps, then use flow to update list item based on the uploaded excel file.(Not fully compliant, need to make some changes)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QaiM8SeWfM

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Update-Sharepoint-List-From-Excel-File/td-p/111477